# How can I use Kendo AutoComplete in Grid column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-autocomplete

I'm trying to convert a Kendo UI grid column from a dropdown to an Kendo AutoComplete. I'm using an MVVM pattern and can't find any examples that like mine. Here is what I have so far:

**In my viewModel:**

```
viewModel = kendo.observable({
suggestedVendor: { "SuggestedVendor": "" },
suggestedVendorDropDownDataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        ... returns a list of Suggested Vendors
  }),

suggestedVendorDropdownEditor: function (container, options) {

        var input = $("<input id='selecteditem' />");
        input.attr("SuggestedVendor", options.field);
        input.appendTo(container);
        input.kendoAutoComplete({
            dataSource: this.suggestedVendorDropDownDataSource,
            dataTextField: "SuggestedVendor",
            dataValueField: "SuggestedVendor",
            dataBind:"value:' + options.field + '"

        });
```

**The field in my grid:**

```
{ field: "SuggestedVendor", 
  title: "Suggested Vendor", 
  editor: viewModel.suggestedVendorDropdownEditor, 
  template: "#= (data.SuggestedVendor == null) ? '' : data.SuggestedVendor #" },
```

I can enter the suggested vendor field and it seems to act like an autocomplete but never returns and data. I can try and create a fiddle if the problem is not immediately obvious.

**EDIT:**

I figured out how to do what I needed with the help of a fiddle I found. I forked it and although the fields are different, it does what I needed. [Here is the fiddle I forked to](http://jsfiddle.net/AkAlan/YBDjA/1/).

I ended up changing my editor code like so:

```
 suggestedVendorDropdownEditor: function (container, options) {
        $('<input id= "selectedItem" data-bind="value: ' + options.field + ' "/>')
            .appendTo(container).kendoAutoComplete({
                dataSource: viewModel.suggestedVendorDropDownDataSource,
                dataTextField: "SuggestedVendor",
                dataValueField: "SuggestedVendor"
        });

      var autoComplete =$("#selectedItem").data("kendoAutoComplete");
      autoComplete.list.width(300);

    }
```

Comment: what do you mean with "it never returns any data"? one problem is that you're trying to define dataBind as an option on the autocomplete which doesn't exist - you should put that in the input html you create ( data-bind="value: ' + options.field +'" );  a demo would probably help

Comment: @Lars Hoppner, Thanks for pointing out my mistake, it helped me figure out how to achieve what I needed. I edited my post to include the solution I found.

Comment: you should post it as an answer instead so people know you no longer need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it figured out after getting advice from the comment by Lars. Here is the code:

```
suggestedVendorDropdownEditor: function (container, options) {
    $('<input id= "selectedItem" data-bind="value: ' + options.field + ' "/>')
        .appendTo(container).kendoAutoComplete({
            dataSource: viewModel.suggestedVendorDropDownDataSource,
            dataTextField: "SuggestedVendor",
            dataValueField: "SuggestedVendor"
    });

  var autoComplete =$("#selectedItem").data("kendoAutoComplete");
  autoComplete.list.width(300);

}
```

Comment: invalid answer. the Autocomplete widget does not have a 'dataValueField' option